# Apache redirection between domain1.com and domain2.com with load balancer in role

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, redirect, centos7, amazon-elb

I have two identical applications binded to port 3000, using the classic load balancer to switch between 2 EC2 servers for fault control. We are using domain1.com(ELB DNSlinked) and domain2.com(ELB DNSlinked) for those two applications. Now, I have to setup a redirection at apache level, tried RewriteEngine's several combinations but none is working. Has anyone ever worked with similar structure or anyone else can help?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName olddomain.com 
ServerAlias www.olddomain.com 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}!newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.)$ newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
</VirtualHost>
```

And

`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newdomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]`

Comment: Show your attempts with results.  Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You can edit your question and put everything in there, with the proper format (icon `{}` in the editor) and indentated.  Same with comments, you can edit them (for 5 minutes), or delete them.  Here I suggest you put all information in the question, and delete the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this buy the below configuration;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ProxyPreserveHost On

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker/1.0
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker/1.0
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker/1.0
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```